# Странные пробелы между селекторами при увеличении масштаба в браузерах

Tags: html, css

Когда масштаб страницы 100%, то все нормально, проблем со стилями нет. Но если увеличивать масштаб в Хроме или Фаерфоксе, то появляются странные пробелы между дивами:

[image]

Как это можно исправить? И в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно конечно видеть код, но я предполагаю, что размеры сайта в пикселях, поэтому при масштабировании не всегда размер в пикселях делиться/умножается без остатка, поэтому браузер округляет цифры, например 939,5 пх = 940 пх. Правда странно, что проблема в файрфоксе, он обычно масштабирует все прекрасно.

Comment: да, все размери в пикселях. Скорее всего это и причина. Но как этого избежать? Неужели нужно все переводить в проценты?

Comment: Нет переводить все в проценты не нужно, правда должен заметить что при масштабировании сайта можно допускать такие одно пиксельные промахи, это не критично, главное чтобы блоки не съезжали со своих мест. Но если это для вас принципиально, можно попробовать "немного" переверстать блок, но определенных рекомендаций нет.

Comment: ну ничего не съезжает, но как-то некрасиво получается если увеличить

Comment: а нельзя сделать какой-то див подложку с серым фоном и при масштабирование, когда он будет выглядывать, то фон сольется и не будет видно белого